# How define what should i do with uncompetible mobile screen Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a good picture on Nexus6(1440,2560) 560 dpi . When i download APK and sent it to my teacher ( her phone is also 2560x1440(Motorola Droid Turbo) ) And picture is next on her phone:
[image]

And what should be expected:[image]

Middle button should have been on white place and there should have been 2 more image buttons from a right side. I created layout-normal and layout-large. Also created drawable-mdpi,ldpi,xdpi. What have i do?? Please help or give any usefull information how to make screen size on this motorola same as on Nexus 6.

Layout.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/main_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/fon" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/goLay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="45dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cup"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/cup" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/menu" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton

            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="119dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="295dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="480dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"

            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/play"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"

            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/settings" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/coins"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"

            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/coins" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Provide your layout declaration in xml, and if it is modified from the source code add the source code too. There can be plenty of issues.

Comment: Also you can add expected version from Nexus

Comment: @Gralls Updated. As you can see it is ok like on most phone emulators

Comment: This white area is a part of the background right?

Comment: @Gralls no, sorry . It is my fault. I made a screen and cut in a paint. There is no white area on a backround. All my background - picture that has size [match parent , match parent].

Comment: No no I meant the one in the center :D where Play button (I guess?) should be placed

Comment: @Gralls oh, yes. That is just part of my background image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in very large margin values and differences in density of pixels per inch. Nexus 6 is 6 inches in diagonal, while Motorola Droid Turbo is 5.2 inches. Simply it means that a view with top margin of `1 dp` will travel further on Motorola Droid Turbo because it has ~565 ppi density (pixels per inch) while Nexus 6 has only ~493 ppi. [More on screen sizes](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities).

Try to rewrite this layout using `ConstraintLayout`.

I'll give you an example and you will update it as required. Notice attributes I have separated with a newline. These are defining the relative position of your views. "Who is next to who".

Before it will start working you will need to add one more dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
```

More info on [how to add dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/fon" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cup"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/cup"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="39dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cup" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="119dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/play"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/settings"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/coins" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/coins"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/coins"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @Jugjin, you are welcome. Learn about constraint layout and avoid large fixed values.